# I don't know what the author trying to say

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrases, spoken-english

I was doing my revision, and I found these sentences in the grammar book I was using:

1) ***I know that*** a spider is a type of arthropod that makes webs to trap and eat prey.

2) ***I know what*** you mean, but I can't come to terms with you.

3) ***I wonder what*** he can do to help his pet.

As you can see, the authors have come out with three different constructions---**as bolded.**

What do they really want to highlight?

Cheers!

Comment: Are they talking about when to use *that* and when to use *what*?

Comment: Yup, I think so too... but in what sense?

Comment: Yes---Thanks! The sentence is like that. What I did not mention is that the sentences are in a dialogue form. They are spoken English.

Comment: Ah well. Quite often the spoken word breaks so many written word rules (or indeed, has it's own rules)

Comment: It should be ***a*** *type of* ***arthropod*** (singular).